# File Systems - Memory-Mapped Files libraries

Tags: c, winapi

I need to use Memory-Mapped Files to implement some virtual file system in c.
I was included  winbase.h for this case , but i have many errors from this library like:

```
Error   1   error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'PVOID'  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winbase.h   250 1   FileIO
Error   2   error C2059: syntax error : '}' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winbase.h   251 1   FileIO
Error   3   error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'hEvent' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winbase.h   253 1   FileIO
Error   4   error C2059: syntax error : ';' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winbase.h   253 1   FileIO
Error   5   error C2059: syntax error : '}' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winbase.h   254 1   FileIO
Error   6   error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'LPOVERLAPPED'   c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winbase.h   258 1   FileIO
Error   7   error C2059: syntax error : '}' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winbase.h   261 1   FileIO
Error   8   error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'LPVOID' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winbase.h   265 1   FileIO
Error   9   error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'bInheritHandle' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winbase.h   266 1   FileIO
Error   10  error C2059: syntax error : ';' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winbase.h   266 1   FileIO
Error   11  error C2059: syntax error : '}' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winbase.h   267 1   FileIO
Error   12  error C2016: C requires that a struct or union has at least one member  c:
```

...

I was included intsafe.h before winbase.h. Is i need another libraries to be included to be able to use winbase.h in my c application?
Thanks for advice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include windows.h instead of winbase.h.

winbase.h doesn't include many of the typedef's for things like PVOID.

Comment: I need to use MSDN code lke : MMFiles[wParam-IDM_MMFCREATE].hFile is not supported in windows.h

Comment: Please include the problemetic source code or a link to the MSDN page with a bad code sample, I've no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: Sorry. I need to use MMF interface : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810613.aspx to create MM object , read, write...

Comment: @user That article is 20 years old. It was written when Windows 3.1 was the latest new thing. It presents excerpts from the source code to a long forgotten app. You asked a question about a compile error. Now you have changed the topic. This looks like the answer to the question you asked. If you want to ask another question about memory mapped files then please do so. If you want my advice I think you need to slow down and learn the basics. File mapping objects are tricky. You have to have the basics in place before you tackle them.